# A closed subspace of $C([0,1])$ with all functions of bounded variation has finite dimension

Tags: functional-analysis, bounded-variation

In several papers on spaceability I found cited the following theorem of Levine and Milman (1940):

Theorem: Let $E$ be a closed subspace of $C([0,1])$ (that is $C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ endowed with the maximum norm $\|\cdot\|_\infty$) such that each $f \in E$ is of bounded variation. Then $\dim E < \infty$.

I woluld like to see a proof of this theorem but couldn't find one neither online nor offline. So, I tried
to prove it myself, but I got stuck. Here's my attempt: Let $\|f\|_v := |f(0)| + Var_f([0,1])$, and note that $\|f\|_\infty \le \|f\|_v$  for each $f \in C([0,1]) \cap BV([0,1])$. Set
$$
 A_n:=\{f \in E: \|f\|_v \le n\}, \quad n \in \mathbb{N}.
 $$
Each $A_n$ is a closed subset of $E$ (note that $E$ is endowed with $\|\cdot\|_\infty$) and $E= A_1\cup A_2 \cup A_3 \cup \dots$.
By Baire's Theorem some $A_n$ contains a closed ball of $E$. Thus the closed unit ball $B_1(E)$ is contained in some $A_n$. This implies that $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ and $\|\cdot\|_v$ are equivalent norms on $E$.

Now, I would like to prove that $B_1(E)$ is compact. If you replace for a moment "of bounded variation" by "Lipschitz continuous", then Arzela-Ascoli could be applied at this point and $\dim E < \infty$ would follow. But a closed and bounded subset $M$ of
$C([0,1])$ with the property that $\|f\|_v \le c$ for a constant $c$ and each $f \in M$ is not compact, in general (e.g.
$M=\{t \mapsto t^n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$). Thus, in a proof of compactness of $B_1(E)$ the vector space structure of $E$ should play a central role. I can explain by an example what I mean by that: Consider the functions $f_n:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$, $n \ge 2$ defined as
$$
f_n(x)=nx ~ (x \in [0,1/n]), ~~ f_n(x)=2-nx ~ (x \in [1/n,2/n]), ~~ f_n(x)=0 ~ (x \in [2/n,1]).
$$
There is a sequence $(n_k)$ such that $\|f_{n_1} + \dots +f_{n_k}\|_\infty$ is uniformly bounded in $k$ and $\|f_{n_1} + \dots + f_{n_k}\|_v \to \infty$ as $k \to \infty$. Thus $f_n \in E$ $(n \ge 2)$ is impossible.

So, I assumed that $\dim E = \infty$ and tried to construct functions in $E$ with $\|f\|_\infty$ small but $\|f\|_v$ big, but didn't succeed. A second idea leading to nowhere up to now was that Helly's First Theorem could help: It's known that each sequence in $B_1(E)$ has a pointwise convergent subsequence.

So, three questions:

1. Can somebody finish this proof?
2. Is there a better (easier) proof?
3. Is there an accessible reference with a proof of this theorem?

Thanks for any support.

Edit: The Lemma mentioned by daw in the comments would indeed finish the proof: Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence in $B_1(E)$, w.l.o.g. pointwise convergent (Helly). Then it is a Cauchy sequence in $E$: Otherwise there is some $\varepsilon_0 > 0$ such that
$$
\forall n \exists k_n,l_n \ge n: ~ \|f_{k_n}-f_{l_n}\|_\infty \ge \varepsilon_0.
$$
But $f_{k_n}-f_{l_n} \to 0$ pointwise as $n \to \infty$, hence by the Lemma $\|f_{k_n}-f_{l_n}\|_\infty \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, a contradiction.

Thus all is reduced to prove the following **Lemma**: If $(f_n)$ is a bounded sequence in $E$ with $f_n \to 0$ pointwise, then $\|f_n\|_\infty \to 0$.

Comment: Have you tried to find a counterexample ?

Comment: I considered the possibility that (even old) published theorems can be wrong. But I have no idea how to construct a counterexample. However my feeling is that it is true.

Comment: Yes my bad I overlooked the closedness criterion.

Comment: mathreviews has the following hint: The proof goes by way of the following lemma: If a sequence of bounded functions in E converges to zero at every point of the interval, it also converges uniformly.

Comment: That's a good point. Reminds of Dini's Thm. I will think about that.

Comment: Isn't the example $f_n=t^n$ a counterexample to the proposed proof? Helly would give convergence pointwise to a discontinuous function.

Comment: No. If $t \mapsto t^n$ would be in $E$ for each $n$ then $E$ would contain all polynomials and as $E$ is closed then $E=C([0,1])$ would follow. But $E$ only contains functions of bounded variation.

Comment: @Gerd: I agree; my point is that in your proposed proof you're not guaranteeing that the limit provided by Helly's theorem is continuous and without it the uniform convergence can't happen.

Comment: That's right, but that's no problem. If the Lemma is true then from pointwise convergence to whatever you get that it is a Cauchy sequence with respect to $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ and then the limit is continuous.

Comment: @Jose27: To make this clearer: The Lemma is applied to the sequence $(f_{k_n}-f_{l_n})$ which is pointwise convergent to $0$.

Comment: What about taking $$f(x)=ax+(1-a)x^2$$, then it's closed in C(0;1), it's increasing so telescoping, hence of bounded variation ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Which subspace $E$ do you mean? Your $f$ is a polynomial, hence of bounded variation on $[0,1]$. To make it clear: $E$ is a vector subspace.

Comment: Yes again my bad, it is of dimension 2, what about : $$ax+(1-a)x^a$$, is this set of infinite dimension ? The index is here the continuous a in 0;1 ?

Comment: Sorry, again I can't see a set or subspace. Do you mean $span \{x \mapsto x^a:a \in [0,1]\}$? This aubspace is not closed.

Comment: Yes the subset $$\{f_a(x)=x^a:a\in[1;2]\}$$ it is a closed subset of C[0;1] but its dimension as a linear vector space is $$\aleph_1$$ ?

Comment: Your set is indeed closed, but it is not a vectorspace. Its span is indeed infinite dimensional but not closed. I think you mix up sets and vectorspaces.

Comment: That the span is not closed I don't understand  the functions generated are $$\int f(a)x^a da$$ which are continuous ?

Comment: @Wraith1995 This only shows that your sequence does not lie in $E$. It does not answer the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Using somewhat advanced results from the theory of Banach spaces
> (in particular, [Dvoretzky's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvoretzky%27s_theorem)),
> one can make the idea suggested by @Gio67 for constructing
> functions $h \in E$ with total variation much bigger than their $L^\infty$-norm
> into a rigorous proof.

Let us assume towards a contradiction that there exists an infinite-dimensional,
closed subspace $E \subset C([0,1])$ satisfying $E \subset BV$.
As noted by the OP and also shown in the answer by @Gio67, there then exists
a constant $M > 0$ satisfying $\mathrm{Var}(f) \leq M \cdot \| f \|_\infty$
for all $f \in E$.

In the following, consider $E$ as a Banach space equipped with the norm $\| \cdot \|_\infty$.
Then, Dvoretzky's theorem
(in the version given [in this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0001870870900320))
shows for any given $N \in \mathbb{N}$ that there exists a subspace
$V_N \subset E$ of dimension $\dim V_N = 2 N$ and such that $d(V_N, \ell_2^{2N}) < 2$,
meaning that there exists an isomorphism $T : V_{N} \to \ell_2^{2N}$ satisfying
$\| T \| \cdot \| T^{-1} \| < 2$.
Here, $\ell_2^{2N}$ is $\mathbb{R}^{2N}$, equipped with the standard Euclidean norm.

Fix a basis $(f_1,\dots,f_{2N})$ for $V_N$.
Then, Theorem 2 in [this](https://msp.org/camcos/2006/1-1/p07.xhtml) paper
shows that there exist $x_1,\dots,x_{2N} \in [0,1]$ (so-called Fekete points) and functions
$g_1,\dots,g_{2 N} : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ with $\| g_i \|_{\infty} \leq 2$ and such that
$$
  f = \sum_{\ell=1}^{2 N} f(x_\ell) \, g_\ell
  \qquad \forall \, f \in V_{N}.
  \tag{$\ast$}
$$

It is not too difficult to see that
$$
  g_1,\dots,g_{2N} \in V_N
  \quad \text{and} \quad
  g_i (x_k) = \delta_{i,k}.
  \tag{$\lozenge$}
$$
Indeed, first note that $(\ast)$ implies $V_N \subset \mathrm{span} \{ g_1,\dots,g_{2N} \}$.
Since $\dim V_N = 2 N$, this easily implies $V_N = \mathrm{span} \{ g_1,\dots,g_{2N} \}$
and in particular $g_1,\dots,g_{2N} \in V_N$.
Hence, the linear maps $S : V_N \to \mathbb{R}^{2N}, f \mapsto (f(x_i))_{1 \leq i \leq 2N}$
and $R : \mathbb{R}^{2 N} \to V_N, c \mapsto \sum_{\ell=1}^{2N} c_\ell \, g_\ell$ are well-defined.
By $(\ast)$, we see $R S = \mathrm{id}_{V_N}$.
Therefore, $R$ is surjective and $S$ is injective.
Since all dimensions agree, this means that $R,S$ are both bijective with
$S = R^{-1}$ and hence $S R = \mathrm{id}_{\mathbb{R}^{2N}}$.
This easily implies $g_i (x_k) = \delta_{i,k}$.

Equation $(\lozenge)$ implies in particular that $x_i \neq x_j$ for $i \neq j$.
Hence, by relabeling, we can assume that $0 \leq x_1 < x_2 < \dots < x_{2N} \leq 1$.
Now, let $(\epsilon_i)_{i=1,\dots,N}$ be independent Rademacher random variables
(that is, $\mathbb{P}(\epsilon_i = 1) = \mathbb{P}(\epsilon_i = -1) = \frac{1}{2}$).

> The idea is to use these Rademacher random variables and the fact that $V_N$
> is "almost a Hilbert space" to introduce a suitable form of "almost orthogonality",
> in order to produce a function with $L^\infty$ norm of order $O(\sqrt{N})$ but with
> total variation of order $O(N)$.

Explicitly, note that if $h_1,\dots,h_N$ are elements of a Hilbert space $H$, then
$$
  \mathbb{E}
  \Big\|
    \sum_{i=1}^N \epsilon_i \, h_i
  \Big\|_H^2
  = \sum_{i,j = 1}^N
    \Big(
      \langle h_i,h_j \rangle_H
      \cdot \mathbb{E} [\epsilon_i \epsilon_j]
    \Big)
  = \sum_{i=1}^N
      \| h_i \|_H^2 ,
$$
since
$\mathbb{E} [\epsilon_i \epsilon_j] = \mathbb{E} [\epsilon_i] \cdot \mathbb{E} [\epsilon_j] = 0$
whenever $i \neq j$.
Therefore, using the operator $T : V_N \to \ell_2^{2N}$ that we got from Dvoretzky's theorem,
we see
\begin{align*}
  \mathbb{E}
  \Big\|
    \sum_{i=1}^N
      \epsilon_i \, g_{2 i}
  \Big\|_\infty^2
  & = \mathbb{E}
    \Big\|
      T^{-1}
      \sum_{i=1}^N
        \epsilon_i \, T g_{2 i}
    \Big\|_\infty^2 \\
  & \leq \| T^{-1} \|^2
         \cdot \mathbb{E}
               \Big\|
                 \sum_{i=1}^N
                   \epsilon_i \, T g_{2 i}
               \Big\|_{\ell_2^{2N}}^2 \\
  & =    \| T^{-1} \|^2 \cdot \sum_{i=1}^N \| T g_{2 i} \|_{\ell_2^{2N}}^2 \\
  & \leq \| T^{-1} \|^2 \cdot \| T \|^2 \cdot \sum_{i=1}^N \| g_{2 i} \|_{\infty}^2
    \leq 16 \cdot N ,
\end{align*}
since $\| T^{-1} \| \cdot \| T \| < 2$ and $\| g_i \|_\infty \leq 2$.
In particular, there exists at least one choice
of $\epsilon_1,\dots,\epsilon_N \in \{ \pm 1 \}$ such that
$$
  h := \sum_{i=1}^N
         \epsilon_i \, g_{2 i}
    \in V_N
$$
satisfies
$$
  \| h \|_\infty \leq \sqrt{16 \cdot N} = 4 \sqrt{N},
  \quad \text{and hence} \quad
  \mathrm{Var}(h)
  \leq M \cdot \| h \|_\infty
  \leq 4 M \sqrt{N}.
$$

To complete the proof, note that $(\lozenge)$ and the definition of $h$
imply that $h(x_\ell) = 0$ for $\ell$ odd
and that $h(x_{2 i}) = \epsilon_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq N$.
Therefore,
$$
  \mathrm{Var}(h)
  \geq \sum_{\ell=1}^{2N - 1}
         \bigl|h(x_{\ell+1}) - h(x_\ell)\bigr|
  \geq \sum_{i = 1}^{N}
         \bigl|h(x_{2 i}) - h(x_{2 i - 1})\bigr|
  =    \sum_{i=1}^{N}
         |\epsilon_i|
  =    N.
$$
Hence, we see that $N \leq \mathrm{Var}(h) \leq 4 M \sqrt{N}$,
where $M$ is fixed and $N \in \mathbb{N}$ can be chosen arbitrarily large.
This is clearly impossible and thus provides the desired contradiction.

Comment: This is very interesting !

Comment: Nice proof, thanks. I needed a while to understand it.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a complete answer, just an idea for possible proof.

The space $BV([0,1])$ of functions of bounded variation is a Banach space with
the norm
$$
\Vert f\Vert_{BV}=|f(0)|+\operatorname*{Var}f.
$$
Consider the space $Z=\{f\in C([0,1]):\,\operatorname*{Var}f<\infty\}$ endowed
with the norm
$$
\Vert f\Vert_{Z}=\Vert f\Vert_{\infty}+\operatorname*{Var}f.
$$
It is a Banach space, since if we take a Cauchy sequence in $Z$, it is a
Cauchy sequence in $BV([0,1])$ and in $C([0,1])$ and so it converges to a
function in $Z$.

Now consider the linear function
\begin{align*}
T  & :E\rightarrow Z\\
f  & \mapsto f
\end{align*}
If $f_{n}\rightarrow f$ in $E$ and $T(f_{n})\rightarrow g$ in $Z$, then $f=g$.
Hence, $T(f)=g$. It follows by the closed graph theorem that $T$ is
continuous, that is, there exists $M>0$ such that
$$
\Vert T(f)\Vert_{Z}\leq M\Vert f\Vert_{\infty}%
$$
for all $f\in E$. In particular,
$$
\operatorname*{Var}f\leq M\Vert f\Vert_{\infty}%
$$
for all $f\in E$.

Now the idea would be to use the fact that $E$ has infinite dimension to find a
function $f\in E$ such that $\Vert f\Vert_{\infty}=1$ and $\operatorname*{Var}%
f>M$.
If we consider $n$ points $x_{1},\ldots, x_{n}\in\lbrack0,1]$ we can find
$f\in E$ such that $f\neq0$ and $f(x_{1})=\ldots=f(x_{n})=0$. Indeed, if not,
we consider the function $L:E\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}$ given by
$L(f)=(f(x_{1}),\ldots,f(x_{n}))$. Then $L$ is linear and $\ker L=\{0\}$,
which implies that $E$ has finite dimension.

Using this fact, we can construct by induction a sequence of functions $f_{n}$
and of points $x_{n}$, such that $\max|f_{n}|=|f_{n}(x_{n})|>0$ and
$f_{n}(x_{k})=0$ for all $k=1,\dots,n-1$. By rescaling, we can assume that
$\max|f_{n}|=1$.
Now one should try to use this fact to construct a function in $E$ with $\Vert f\Vert_{\infty}=1$ and $n$ ordered points such that $f(x_{2k})=0$ and $f(x_{2k+1})=1$.  I am not quite sure how.

Comment: This gives an alternative proof for that $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ and $\|\cdot\|_{BV}$ are equivalent norms on $E$ (with the Closed Graph Thm. instead of Baire's Thm.). The main problem is indeed to find a function  $f \in E$ with $\|f\|_\infty$ small but $\|f\|_{BV}$ big,

Comment: Yes. I added more details to what I have in mind but I am not sure on how to make it work.

Comment: Since nobody else gave a satisfactory answer, I will award you the bounty, lest it go to waste. One can certainly show (based on arguments from linear algebra, given that the space $E$ is infinite dimensional) that if one chooses points $x_1 < \dots < x_n$ suitably, one can "interpolate" arbitrary given values $y$ at these points via a function $f_y \in E$. However, I can't seem to get a better bound than $\| f_y\|_\infty \leq \| y\|_{\ell^1}$ in general, and this is (barely) not enough to make your argument fly.

Comment: I don't know too much about geometry in Banach spaces, however. It could be that to people in the field it is well-known that one can improve the (trivial) bound that I just gave, if one chooses the sampling points suitably.

Comment: Using a bit of Banach space geometry, I now found out that one can indeed make your sketched argument into a rigorous one. I will post the proof in a few hours.